MILP with "unnecessary" continuous variables
This is a theoretical question. I have an integer programming model where I use a series of continuous variables for clarity purposes. These continuous variables are obtained as the product of some binary variables and some continuous parameters, so they are not necessary for the proper functioning of the model. Does this imply that it is a MILP model instead of an IP model?
Here it's a part of my model:

Here, all lower-case latin letters, except $l_t$, are binary variables; all greek letters are parameters; and all upper-case latin letters, and $l_t$, are those continuous variables I called "unnecessary", because I could delete last 4 constraints and rewrite my objective function as $max\; Z = \sum_t \Big(\sum_d \Big((\Delta_d \cdot \sum_m n_{dmt}) - (\beta_d \cdot \sum_m (\alpha_m \cdot g_{dmt})) - (\phi_d \cdot x_{dt})\Big) - (\zeta \cdot l_t) \Big)$
(I should substitute the complete formula of $l_t$, but I think it is understandable)
So, in this way, $l_t$, $B_{dt}$, $C^D_{dt}$, $C^B_{dt}$ and $C^S_{t}$, are unnecessary for the model.

Some points: 1) if in the final model, you have mixed variables, (e.g. integer and continues), yes the problem is MILP. 2) You can share the model, specifically, the part you have non-linear terms. It gives more chance to better investigate the model. 3) If you have used standard MI(n)LP solvers, they have nice features to linearize the product of the variables under a hood automatically.

I've edited my answer. Thanks.

Your mentioned objective function in the last line is linear if $\Delta, \beta, \alpha, \phi, \zeta$ are constant. It can remain in the objective function without any complaints unless you have a specific purpose for substituting them with the auxiliary variables. The only non-linear term still returns to your fifth constraint which is the product of the binary variables. As I said in my previous comment many of the standard MIP/MIQCP solvers have automated internal mechanisms to linearize those.

Hi Omidi. Sorry for my ignorance. Maybe I'm not understanding you or I didn't explain myself well. I have no problem solving the model. I do it with Pyomo and Gurobi and it works perfectly. My only question is whether, purely theoretically, my model would be an MILP or an IP. Thank you.

This Model is an MIQCP. solver can convert it as an MILP.

Thank you very much!

You can linearize the product in the fifth constraint by introducing one new variable which can be either binary or continuous (your choice). Alternatively, as @A.Omidi said, you can let the solver linearize it. So you can view this as either a MILP or an ILP, depending on how you declare the extra variable.
